# Graphical User Interface while developing Eclipse Plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've done some searching around and found questions similar to this but the answers do not meet my requirement.

I have already finished developing the back-end codes of an Eclipse plug-in. Now, I have to develop the front-end of it. Such as when I click on the plug-in from the Eclipse menu-bar, a new window (within Eclipse) must open and it must show some buttons, drop-downs etc.

Is there a way to develop plug-ins with interfaces? Rather than the normal plug-in that is created from a menu or a button in the action bars of Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to download [Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers Neon](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/neonr) (or later), and Install Window Builder via [Update Site](http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/).

Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers contains the E4 model editor, a graphical tree editor to use for shape the application and its services.

[image]

Here is the link to download Eclipse RCP/RAP Neon R:
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/neonr

WindowBuilder, on the other side, is a great tool to design RCP User Interfaces graphically. So, you can design graphically each single UI with WindowBuilder.

[image: Window Builder to Edit an RCP UI]

Here is the update site to install Window Builder in Eclipse 4.6: http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/

Note: Even if you use Window Builder, you should know basics of SWT, JFace and DataBinding.